# Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

Driving me mad on a personal project; I know I've done this before but elsewhere and don't have the code.  As far as I can see, I'm setting the parameter, I'm setting its value, the connection is open, yet when I try to fill the dataset I get the error 'Procedure or function expects parameter "@test" which was not supplied'.

(This is obviously a simplified test! Same error on this or the real, rather longer code though.)

C#:

```
SqlCommand l_oCmd;
DataSet l_oPage = new DataSet();

l_oCmd = new SqlCommand("usp_test", g_oConn);
l_oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@test", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
l_oCmd.Parameters[0].Value = "hello world";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(l_oCmd);
da.Fill(l_oPage);
```

SQL:

```
create procedure usp_test
(
    @test nvarchar(1000)
)
as
select @test
```

What have I missed?

Comment: What happens if you just use: `l_oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@test", "hello world"));`

Comment: Done both, does the same each way.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Change the command type to Procedure

Comment: Ugh, should have caught that.  That was driving me crazy.

Comment: Long time no ADO.Net. (That's my excuse, I'm sticking with it)

Comment: I had this exact same issue. That's what I get for spending so much time with Entity Framework. I forgot my roots...

Comment: OMG, what a save! I've been retired for eight years now, but decided to have a go at creating a Sql Server driven app. My first in all that time. Having to remind myself about all this old stuff. But this error was driving me batty (not a long drive, btw). I wanted to tell the code "But the darned parm is *right there*!" Finally come back to SO, and here's the answer. Whew! Should have remembered that little detail.